# For NDK How do I target older devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, android-2.2-froyo

I'm just getting started working with NDK and I finally got things building.
I've got a simple hello world c app that I based in no small part on a youtube walk through.

When I got around to running "ndk-build" I get this warning.
APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml

Poking about I realized that this warning is drastic. Under the hood this means that my code won't run on the older devices.. (about 40% market share right now)

Does anyone know how to target the older devices?  What to change and where?

It has been pointed out that this is a repeat of another question. 
It is indeed a repeat of another question; with the small exception of the WHERE clause of the question.
Where is the Application.mk file?

Comment: indeed the same.. Does this work?  Will the code run on the old systems?

Comment: WITH ONE SMALL DIFFERENCE. Could you please tell me where the Application.mk file lives?  I know it wasn't mentioned in the tutorial, and I don't see it anywhere in my folders.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me where the Application.mk file lives?

Quoting the NDK documentation:

> An Application.mk file is usually placed under $PROJECT/jni/Application.mk,
>   where $PROJECT points to your application's project directory.
>
> Another alternative is to place it under a sub-directory of the top-level
>   $NDK/apps directory, e.g.:

```
$NDK/apps/<myapp>/Application.mk
```

> Where  is a short name used to describe your 'application'
>   to the NDK build system (this name doesn't go into your generated
>   shared libraries or your final packages).

You can find the NDK documentation in the `docs/` directory of your NDK installation. The above comes from the `APPLICATION-MK.html` file.